# Interactive Treemap with d3treeR not rendering in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, treemap, htmlwidgets

I am a newbie to Shiny and I am trying to use the **d3TreeR HTML Widget** to display an interactive treemap

I used the following code and it ran perfectly in R:

```
library(readxl)
budget_map <- read_excel(path = 'Trader Dashboard Data Prep Sample.xlsx',sheet='v2',col_names = TRUE)
library(treemap)
budget_treemap <- treemap(budget_map,index=c("Sales Agency","Agency","Advertiser"),vSize="Booked Revenue Net",vColor="Sales Agency",palette = "Set1",type="categorical",title="Australia Budget Map",fontsize.title=22)
library(d3treeR)
d3tree2(budget_treemap)
```

I'm trying to get it to render in Shiny and am using the following code:

```
library(shiny)
library(readxl)
library(treemap)
library(htmlwidgets)
library(data.tree)
library(d3treeR)
budget_map <- read_excel(path = 'C:/Users/rahul/Desktop/30k foot view/Trader Dashboard Data Prep Sample.xlsx',sheet='v2',col_names = TRUE)
budget_treemap <- treemap(budget_map,index=c("Sales Agency","Agency","Advertiser"),vSize="Booked Revenue Net",vColor="Sales Agency",palette = "Set1",type="categorical")

ui <- fluidPage(
  d3tree2Output("au_budget_map")
)


server <- function(input,output){
    output$au_budget_map <- renderD3tree2({budget_treemap})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Attaching sample data to make it reproducible: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2LJXtBTsuhhcnZJeXI3T0kwYW8
I know I might be missing something very evident - but am not able to spot it! Any help would be really great! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`renderD3tree2` accepts result of `d3tree2` as input :

```
output$au_budget_map <- renderD3tree2({d3tree2(budget_treemap)})
```